# how to use .env file in mvn spring-boot:build-image

Tags: spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea, docker-image

I have a spring boot backend and would like to build a docker image from it for deployment. I found out that I can build the image with mvn (mvn spring-boot:build-image). Building the image works, but unfortunately I always get an error message when running the docker image: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Socket fail to connect to host:address=(host=localhost)(port=3306)(type=primary). Connection refused (Connection refused)

However, my .env file has a different host and port entered and locally these are used.

In IntelliJ Idea I have also enabled the .env in the docker image build job.

[image]

How is it possible to build the envs inside the docker image?

Comment: How do you run your docker image? Which command  do you use?
You can use `docker run --env-file=...`

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. I even tried to add every var separately with the -e flag.

Comment: Are you setting the environment variables at runtime (`docker run`)? You can't set them at build time.
What exactly is in your .env file?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I tried setting the envs already in the dockerfile and this time it worked. Is there a way to not have to specify the individual variables line by line in the Dockerfile, but to use a reference to an existing .env file?

Comment: That's what the `--env-file=` CLI option is for. I don't know why it doesn't work for you? Maybe update the question to show what does work and what doesn't work with Docker?